# Uima Ruta StringList

Tags: uima, ruta

Is there a way to iterate StringList in Ruta, provided the strings in the StringList are not present in the input document?

**Sample StringList**

- Television
- Computer
- Tablet
- Sound

**Sample Input Document**

Flat-screen televisions for sale at a consumer electronics store in 2008.
**Television** (TV), sometimes shortened to tele or telly is a telecommunication medium used for transmitting moving images in monochrome (black and white), or in colour, and in two or three dimensions and **sound**. The term can refer to a **television** set, a **television** program ("TV show"), or the medium of **television** transmission. **Television** is a mass medium for advertising, entertainment and news.

**Problem**

I want to get the values, **Computer** and **Tablet** as a result from the output CAS (say as an annotation or a feature). Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently (2.6.1) no way to iterate over a StringList in Ruta as far as I know.

You want to return all entries that are not present in the text?

I have not tried it, but you could maybe use multiple lists, and add entries to one list if they occur in the text and to the other if they do not. Then, you story the second StringList in a feature.

(I would probably use a simple Java analysis engine instead of Ruta)

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*